# How to find the most common value in each column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I have a table that looks like this:

```
category    name1    name2    name3    name4    name5

  1         John      Sam     John     Katy      Cat
  1         John      Ivan    Bob      Andrew    Tom
  1         Sam       Ivan    George   Bob       Tom
  2         Jack      Siri    Elsa     Noah      Anna
  2         Jack      Bob     Tomas    Noah      Tom
```

What I need to do, is to find the most common value in each column for each category. That is, I need the following result:

```
category    name1    name2    name3    name4    name5

  1         John      Ivan    John     Katy      Tom
  2         Jack      Siri    Elsa     Noah      Anna
```

If there are several values with the same frequency, any of them may be chosen.

So far, I have only managed to do that for one column with this script:

```
SELECT top(1) category, name1, COUNT(name1) AS freq
FROM data
GROUP BY category, name1
ORDER BY freq DESC
```

But how do I do that for several columns in SQL Server?

Comment: `So far, I have only found the code to do that with one column` . Why not duplicate the code for other columns as well

Comment: show you code that you did it for 1 column

Comment: category2, name2 : Siri and Bob are equally prevalent, so why have you chosen Siri?

Comment: @Adamszsz added the code to the question

Comment: @MatBailie If there are several values with the same frequency, any of them may be chosen

Comment: @Squirrel I don't know how to combine it correctly

Comment: What about ties? Why John and not Bob or George for name3 in category = 1?

Comment: @forpas  If there are several values with the same frequency, any of them may be chosen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First create a CTE that uses `COUNT()` window function to return the number of times each name occurs in each category and then use `FIRST_VALUE()` window function to get for each column the name that occurs the most:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY category, name1) count1,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY category, name2) count2,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY category, name3) count3,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY category, name4) count4,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY category, name5) count5
  FROM tablename
)
SELECT DISTINCT category,
       FIRST_VALUE(name1) OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY count1 DESC) name1,
       FIRST_VALUE(name2) OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY count2 DESC) name2,
       FIRST_VALUE(name3) OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY count3 DESC) name3,
       FIRST_VALUE(name4) OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY count4 DESC) name4,
       FIRST_VALUE(name5) OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY count5 DESC) name5
FROM cte
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3f0f3a4b40eed5306192f29c4143a42c).

Comment: Simple and elegant. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @OlegIvanytskyi - I'd suggest that (due to your data-structure, not due to forpas) that this breaches the DRY principle (Don't Repeat Yourself) and as such isn't elegant.  The solution to that should be either 'fixing' your data structure, or pivoting it on the fly (as per other answers).  Having to repeat all the real logic for each and every column is a strong code-smell.  I'd also be keen to understand which is most performant / least costly.  *(Just imagine how clean this answer would be if you had one row per name, rather than one column per name...)*

Comment: @MatBailie That would be great indeed, however, I cannot change this structure, as this table is not of my creation. I will definitely take a look at other answers, but this one is simple and short, that's why I marked it as the Answer to my question

Answer (score 1):

One option, with lots of repetition, but accommodating your current structure...

(Though it still has the same non-deterministic/arbitrary behaviour when dealing with equally frequent names)

```
WITH
  counted AS
(
  SELECT
    category,
    name1,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY category, name1)  AS name1_freq,
    name2,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY category, name2)  AS name2_freq
  FROM
    yourTable
),
  ranked AS
(
  SELECT
    category,
    name1,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY name1_freq DESC)  AS name1_rank,
    name2,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY name2_freq DESC)  AS name2_rank
  FROM
    counted
)
SELECT
  category,
  MAX(CASE WHEN name1_rank = 1 THEN name1 END)  AS name1_most_common,
  MAX(CASE WHEN name2_rank = 1 THEN name2 END)  AS name2_most_common
FROM
  ranked
GROUP BY
  category
```

As you can see, that's a LOT of repetition.  Which is why SQL is predicated on normalised data-structures.  So much so that normalising then denormalising your structure may be a valid option...

```
WITH
  normalised(category, col, name) AS
(
            SELECT category, 1, name1 FROM yourTable 
  UNION ALL SELECT category, 2, name2 FROM yourTable
),
  counted AS
(
  SELECT
    category, col, name, COUNT(*) AS freq
  FROM
    normalised
  GROUP BY
    category, col, name
),
  ranked AS
(
  SELECT
    category, col, name,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category, col ORDER BY freq DESC)  AS rank
  FROM
    counted
)
SELECT
  category,
  MAX(CASE WHEN col = 1 THEN name END)  AS name1_most_common,
  MAX(CASE WHEN col = 2 THEN name END)  AS name2_most_common
FROM
  ranked
WHERE
  rank = 1
GROUP BY
  category
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the results in rows, you can unpivot, which makes this much simpler:

```
select category, which, name
from (select t.category, v.which, v.name, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by t.category, v.which order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t cross apply
           (values (1, name1), (2, name2), (3, name3), (4, name4), (5, name4)
           ) v(which, name)
      from t
      group by t.category, v.which, v.name
      ) cwn
where seqnum = 1;
```

You can re-pivot if you want this in columns:

```
with cwn as (
      select t.category, v.which, v.name, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by t.category, v.which order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t cross apply
           (values (1, name1), (2, name2), (3, name3), (4, name4), (5, name4)
           ) v(which, name)
      from t
      group by t.category, v.which, v.name
     )
select category,
       max(case when which = 1 then name end) as name1,
       max(case when which = 2 then name end) as name2,
       max(case when which = 3 then name end) as name3,
       max(case when which = 4 then name end) as name4,
       max(case when which = 5 then name end) as name5
from cwn
where seqnum = 1
group by category
```

Comment: @OlegIvanytskyi . . . You might also find that this is the fastest approach.

Comment: *fastest*? Why? Did you test it? Can you prove that this is fastest?